# Saving data with ajax and json

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, json

I am working on a project that I didn't start and I have an input that is function is to save the data to the data base. The input leaves to this function (SaveData) and it isn't working. I really don't understand much from ajax and json, so could anyone please see what's wrong with this?

The function is this:

```
 function SaveData() {
     var columns = [];

     $("#FeaturedContent_m_visible_cols li").each(function (i, elem) {
        columns[i] = $(elem).attr("colid");
     });

     $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "ConfigList.aspx/SaveConfiguration",
        data: "{ 'jsonData': [" + JSON.stringify(columns) + "] }",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
        },
        error: function (response) {
           alert(jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText).Message);
        }
     });
```

The SaveConfiguration method is this:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
 [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
  public static string SaveConfiguration(dynamic jsonData)
{
 Object[] column = (Object[])jsonData[0];
  string   col_id;
  int      i;

  for (i=0; i<column.Length; i++) {
     col_id = (string)column[i];
  }

  SaveTableConfiguration();

  return "";
  }
```

And the SaveTableConfiguration:

```
 public void SaveTableConfiguration(int list_id, List<TableHeader> lista)
  {
    int           i;
    TableHeader   row;
    SetListConfig set_lconfig = new SetListConfig(m_connection, m_language);

set_lconfig.LoadRecordset("LC_LISTID=" + list_id.ToString(),    m_transaction);
     while (!set_lconfig.IsEOF()) {
        set_lconfig.m_LC_EDITABLE = 0;
        set_lconfig.Update();

        set_lconfig.MoveNext();
     }

     for (i=0; i<lista.Count;i++) {
        row=lista[i];

set_lconfig.LoadRecordset("LC_LISTID=" + list_id.ToString() + " AND                LC_COLTBL='" + row.header_col + "'", m_transaction);
        if (set_lconfig.IsEOF()) {
           set_lconfig.m_LC_EDITABLE = 1;
           set_lconfig.m_LC_ORDER = i+1;
           set_lconfig.Update();
        }
     }
  }
```

Thanks Once more! =)

Comment: Are you receiving the data in c#?

Comment: Use a debugger, See if your client side request is getting to server side `SaveConfiguration` *web method* in `ConfigList.aspx`.

Comment: show the SaveConfiguration method implementation+

Comment: _data: "{ 'jsonData': [" + JSON.stringify(columns) + "] }",_

JSON.stringify a Array into a Array is probably wrong.  
it would leave you with that json:
_{ jsonData: **[ [**  ...  **] ]**  }_

Comment: @Unike Can you define "and it isnt working"? You are not doing anything in the success handler so even if there was a successful call/return nothing would happen.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, assuming the URL is valid and the rest of your html, it looks like your data property is incorrect.  You have:

```
data: "{ 'jsonData': [" + JSON.stringify(columns) + "] }",
```

And in my experience, you should use stringify on the entire piece:

```
data: JSON.stringify({jsonData: columns}),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function SaveData() {
 var columns = [];

 $("#FeaturedContent_m_visible_cols li").each(function (i, elem) {
    columns[i] = $(elem).attr("colid");
 });
var datum={'jsonData':columns};

 $.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "ConfigList.aspx/SaveConfiguration",
    data: JSON.stringify(datum),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
    },
    error: function (response) {
       alert(jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText).Message);
    }
 });
```